# Set my paragrpah to be write right to left

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I create a word document the [DocX project](http://docx.codeplex.com/).

I need to set my paragrpah right-to-left but I don't know what should I do?

```
string fileName = @"D:\Users\John\Documents\DocXExample.docx";

// Create a document in memory:
var doc = DocX.Create(fileName);

// Insert a paragrpah:
doc.InsertParagraph("This is my first paragraph");

// Save to the output directory:
doc.Save();

// Open in Word:
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", fileName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found that ,we should use something like that :

```
        Paragraph p = doc.InsertParagraph(subject);
        p.Direction=Direction.RightToLeft;
```